# Dump and die (dd) within home controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently following a youtube tutorial "Pivot tables and many-to-many relationships in Laravel - Laravel Business'. I finally understand relationships but I am having trouble putting this into practice. I have two tables `user` and `role` as well as a pivot table to connect the two, called `role_user`.

I am using the home controller to test as per the youtube tutorial, however when i attempt to attach a `role_id` to a `user_id` using `dd` the info does not display. Am i doing something wrong within my web.php?

I am new to laravel so i would appreciate any help. Thanks.

HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Role;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user->roles()->attach(1);
        dd($user->roles);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I am trying to do as the below, unfortunately there is nothing in the video re his routes. I have generated a new laravel project for this.

[image]

Comment: Can you add pivot table in the relationship?

Comment: You may need to reload the relationship. Try `$user->load('roles');`, then try to dd it

Comment: yes, its done in the following youtube video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akKWC_vP7sE i am just trying to dd the info using the home controller but unsure how to get this to display via my routes.

Comment: @KerryMckinney can you check `dd($user)` before `attach()`. I think user id 1 not exist. First check user exists or not.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya thank you for this, i have tried this and currently have 2 users created but still returning the laravel welcome page? is there something in my routes i need to change to direct me to the home controller so i can view the dd info?

Comment: You need to be logged in to view/use the HomeController. You could also just replace `return view('welcome');` with the three lines of your HomeController@index method and use `/` to check

Comment: What *do* you get on the page, if nothing is being returned from `dd`?

Comment: @kerbholz I don't see anything that would restrict the use of HomeController. It's not using a middleware on the route or controller.

Comment: @kerbholz thank you, i was unaware i had to be logged in.. many thanks :) its a learning curve!

Comment: @aynber Right, didn't realize OP posted their own HomeController, the "default" HomeController in Laravel uses `auth`

Comment: @KerryMckinney Same for you, my fault, I didn't realize you had your own HomeController there, I was refering to the HomeController that gets created when adding Auth to Laravel. So scratch that part. Sorry. On the other hand, there's `Auth::routes();` -  is this the complete code for the HomeController you have there? Probably, you'd be redirected to login. Anyway

Comment: @kerbholz cheers, i shall take it all on board, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the pivot table in the model where you define relationship:

```
public function roles() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user', 'rold_id', 'user_id' );
}
```

Comment: thanks, i've made this change however I still am unable to view the info I'm trying to dd, do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to display this?

Comment: You don't need to specify the pivot table if it follows certain rules, Laravel will figure out on its own that the table name is `role_user`. Also `role_id` and `user_id` need to be swapped in your code

Comment: @kerbholz You are right but this way we can specify pivot table.